# Scanf ignores user input-saves an irrelevant number

Tags: c, scanf

I'am having a great issue with my code the last few days.While scanf() function seems to work great during my programm, when the programm reaches a certain point,(where I scan a float number),I just enter the value I want to be saved in variable min_dist but when I print it right after,the variable has a completely different value,thus the whole programm is messed up.I am using the free compiler provided with Code::Blocks-could this be a problem?my friend compiles the same programm in his computer, and no problem occurs!Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main() {
 int codeA[50],codeB[50],over[2500][2],numA,numB,min_dist;
 int i,j,k=0 ;
 float xA[50],yA[50],zA[50],xB[50],yB[50],zB[50] ;
 double sq_dist,dist ;

 printf("Enter the number of spots for company A: \n");
 scanf("%d",&numA);
 printf("Enter the number of spots for company B: \n");
 scanf("%d",&numB);

 for (i=0; i<numA; i++) {
  printf("Enter code of company A's spot number %d \n",i+1) ;
  scanf("%d",&codeA[i]) ;
  printf("Enter spot's coordinates: \n");
  printf("On axis X: \n") ;
  scanf("%f",&xA[i]);
  printf("On axis Y: \n");
  scanf("%f",&yA[i]);
  printf("On axis Z: \n");
  scanf("%f",&zA[i]);
 }
 for (i=0; i<numB; i++) {
  printf("Enter code of company B's spot number %d \n",i+1) ;
  scanf("%d",&codeB[i]) ;
  printf("Enter spot's coordinates: \n");
  printf("On axis X: \n") ;
  scanf("%f",&xB[i]);
  printf("On axis Y: \n");
  scanf("%f",&yB[i]);
  printf("On axis Z: \n");
  scanf("%f",&zB[i]);
 }
 printf("Enter the minimum distance between 2 spots \n");
 ****scanf("%d",&min_dist);
 printf("%d",min_dist);****
for (i=0; i<numA; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<numB; j++) {
        sq_dist=(xA[i]-xB[j])*(xA[i]-xB[j]) + (yA[i]-yB[j])*(yA[i]-yB[j]) + (zA[i]-zB[j])*(zA[i]-zB[j]) ;
        dist=sqrt(sq_dist);
         printf("%f \n",dist);
          if (dist<=2) {
            over[k][0]=codeA[i];
            over[k][1]=codeB[j];
            k++ ;
          }
    }
 }
 printf("%d, %f \n",k,dist);
 printf("These spots collide: \n");
 for (i=0; i<k; i++){
    printf("code A: %d       code B:%d \n",over[i][0],over[i][1]);
 }
 for (i=0; i<numA; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<k; j++) {
           if (codeA[i]==over[j][0]) {
            codeA[i]=0 ;
            xA[i]=0;
            yA[i]=0;
            zA[i]=0;
            continue ;
           }
        }
 }
 for (i=0; i<numB; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<k; j++) {
           if (codeB[i]==over[j][1]) {
            codeB[i]=0 ;
            xB[i]=0;
            yB[i]=0;
            zB[i]=0;
            continue ;
           }
        }
 }
 for (i=0; i<numA; i++) {
    if (codeA[i]!=0) {
        printf("Remaining company A's spot code %d \n",codeA[i]) ;
        printf("Coordinates x,y,z: \n %f,%f,%f \n",xA[i],yA[i],zA[i]) ;
    }
 }
 for (i=0; i<numB; i++) {
    if (codeB[i]!=0) {
        printf("Remaining company B's spot code %d \n",codeB[i]) ;
        printf("Coordinates x,y,z: \n %f,%f,%f \n",xB[i],yB[i],zB[i]) ;
    }
 }
}
```

Actually,I get a different wrong result,depending on what I type. For example: When I type 2,as a minimum distance,the number 21.715021 is printed directly after.If I enter 10, 101.705021 (or something like that-can't remember exactly) is printed directly after.If I declare min_dist as a float,a number like 1.025846e-210 is printed directly after.

I highlighted the programm point where the problem occurs.I'am new to c,as well as not a native english speaker,so please excuse me for any grammar/syntax mistakes.

Comment: If it works on one system but not on another, this often indicates a memory access problem. Since you're using a bunch of arrays, you need to check that you have no out-of-bounds indices. Also, you need to check that the format specs on the scanf's and printf's match the data types. Unfortunately, I can't find any such errors, but maybe you can.

Comment: I already did mate,and couldn't find a problem.Actually, the indices were wrong at first,but even when I corrected them,no progress!

Comment: You seem to know what you're doing, then. If you add the "C" tag to your question you may get more views.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned reading a floating-point number into `min_dist`, but the call is:

```
scanf("%d",&min_dist);
```

This is trying to read an integral into `min_dist`. Did you mean to use `%f`?

Comment: At first min_dist was declared as a float,thus I used %f.But when I noticed the problem,I declared min_dist as an integer to see if anything changes,but I got nothing.Actually,I get a different wrong result,depending on what I type. For example: When I type 2,as a minimum distance,the number 21.715021 is printed directly after.If I declare min_dist as a float,a number like 1.025846e-210 is printed.